# OS installation failure

Tags: boot, ati

Decided to try Linux after a decade of using Windows, but unfortunately on setup met these issues.

```
[8.555642] ACPI PCC probe failed
starting version 219
And later goes huge list of other errors like
[8.640167] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Invalid ROM contents
[8.967939] usb 3-5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[10.358068] usb 3-5: device not accepting address 5, error -32

BusyBoxv 1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-ubuntu1) built-in shell(ash)
(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

Absolutely have no idea how to deal with it, even after searching on forums, personally to me looks like a compatibility error with my graphics card, which is AMD R9 270X.

Will be very thankful for any suggestions what actions to take, THANK YOU!!!